# Forms,looping scrips and cross platforms problems

Tags: c#, forms

i'm working on the dedicated server of my game,and i'm using forms for it,because 
it is more friendly for the hosters to,well,manage the server,basically.
But i'm having a problem.

```
                MainServer main = new MainServer();
                //Application.Run(main);
                main.Show();
                while (0 == 0)
                {
                    ProgramServer.UpdateServerStuff(main);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    main.Update();
                }
```

The forms must be running and the following script on the while() must be running while the form is open and operable.
But the problem is,the while(0 == 0) runs well and loop,but the form freezes the image,basically only shows the loading cursor on it.
I could try to use thread,but it gives the error of cross platform when i try to change some form elements,like the button text or if it's active.
There is any way of making the script on the while() update with the form?Or make the form operable while the script on the while runs aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and drop inside your loop:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

This will allow events to continue to be processed for the forms.

However, I would not do it this way and recommend you rethink your approach using something like `BackgroundWorker` and using the `ReportProgress` and `Invoke` methods to talk back to the UI thread.

Comment: i needed to wait 10 minutes to do it,this delay is annoying.